# MetaClass in Python

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass

I am trying to create a Meta-Class for my Class.
I have tried to print information about my class in meta-class

Now I have created two objects of my class
But Second object gets created without referencing my Meta-Class

Does Meta Class gets called only once per Class??

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __new__(cls,name,bases,attr):
        print (f"name {name}")
        print (f"bases {bases}")
        print (f"attr {attr}")
        print ("Space Please")

        return super(Singleton,cls).__new__(cls,name,bases,attr)

class Multiply(metaclass = Singleton):
    pass
     
objA = Multiply()
objB = Multiply()

print (objA)
print (objB)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python)

Comment: If you will add a `print("hi")` before the object creation and change to `print(objB.__class__.__class__)` you will see that both objects are part of the meta-class. The body of the `__new__` method is executed once when the `class` statement is reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - the metaclass's `__new__` and `__init__` methods are called only when the class is created. After that, in your example, the class will be bound to the`Multiply` name. In many aspects, it is just an object like any other in Python. When you do `objA = Multiply()` you are not creating a new instance of `type(Multiply)`, which is the metaclass - you are creating a new instance of `Multiply` itself: `Multiply.__new__` and `Multiply.__init__` are called.

Now, there is this: the mechanism in Python which make `__new__`  and `__init__` be called when creating an instance is the code in the metaclass `__call__` method. That is, just as when you create any class with a `__call__` method and use an instance of it with the calling syntax `obj()` will invoke `type(obj).__call__(obj)`, when you do `Multiply()` what is called (in this case) is `Singleton.__call__(Multiply)`.
Since it is not implemented, Singleton's superclass, which is `type` `__call__` method is called instead - and it is in there that `Multiply.__new__` and `__init__` are called.

That said, there is nothing in the code above that would make your classes behave as "singletons". **And more importantly** you don't need a metaclass to have a singleton in Python. I don't know who invented this thing, but it keeps circulating around.

**First**, if you really need a singleton, all you need to do is to write a plain class, no special anything, create your single instance, and document that the instance should be used. Just as people use `None` - no one keeps getting a reference to `Nonetype` and keep calling it to get a `None` reference:

```py
class _Multiply:
   ...

# document that the code should use this instance:
Multiply = _Multiply()
```

**second** Alternatively, if your code have a need, whatsoever, for instantiating the class that should be a singleton where it will be used, you can use the class' `__new__` method itself to control instantiation, no need for a metaclass:

```py
class Multiply:
     _instance = None
     def __new__(cls):
         if not cls._instance:
             cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)    
             # insert any code that would go in `__init__` here:
             ...
             ...
         return cls._instance
```

**Third** just for demonstration purposes, *please* don't use this, the metaclass mechanism to have singletons can be built in the `__call__` method:

```py
class Singleton(type):
    registry = {}
    def __new__(mcls,name,bases,attr):
        print(f"name {name}")
        print(f"bases {bases}")
        print(f"attr {attr}")
        print("Class created")
        print ("Space Please")

        return super(Singleton,mcls).__new__(cls,name,bases,attr)
    
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        registry = type(cls).registry
        if cls not in registry:
            print(f"{cls.__name__} being instantiated for the first time")
            registry[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kw)
        else:
            print(f"Attempting to create a new instance of {cls.__name__}. Returning single instance instead")
        return registry[cls]
        

class Multiply(metaclass = Singleton):
    pass
```

Comment: If you consider the question to be answered, you should indicate that by accepting it (check mark close to the vote-score)